# Stop a view from being processed?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In my controller I call this via an AJAX call:

```
$data = Lib::index();
    $view = View::make('index')
        ->with('data', $data)
        ->render();
    return $view;
```

The above fails because the correct table does not exist in my database.

In Lib Index method, I catch this failure with:

```
catch (QueryException $e) {

    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not found');
    exit;

}
```

I catch the above error with the .fail deferred method of ajax call with jquery.

All of the above works (and fails as expected) until I start calling the $data var in my view.

Things like:

```
@foreach($data as $asset)
```

I get errors:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

But the view should not even be processed as the query error is caught.

I've tried stuff like isset and isempty on teh data var in teh view, but it still processes the view.

Why is the view still being processed and how can I stop it?

Comment: Try to dont use QueryException but Exception?!

Comment: But the error is catching fine. It's the view that is being processed no matter what for some reason.

Comment: Which line does the error occur? Is that in the view?

Comment: Yes the view, I've posted a simplified question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737961/if-statements-in-blade-templating

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what causes this, but there are a couple of simple solutions:

1. instead of trying to set the 404 header and return, use Laravel's [HTTP Exceptions](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#http-exceptions).
2. if you must catch that error in the `Lib::index()` method, you could try rethrowing a `\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException`. Laravel's default error handlers will then catch it and return it to the client.
3. finally, a third alternative is to catch the exception outside of the `Lib::index()` method and then return something different.

For example:

```
try {
    $data = Lib::index();
    $view = View::make('index')
        ->with('data', $data)
        ->render();
    return $view;
} catch(QueryException $e) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not found');
    exit;
}
```