# If statements in blade templating?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have an empty set of data, in my blade template I check for this via:

```
@if(empty($data))
   It's empty!
@else
   @foreach($data as $asset)
      $asset->alt
   @endforeach
@endif
```

The problem is, I get the error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

But this should not even happen as the else of the if statement should not even run. Why is this happening?

I've checked and 'It's empty' is displayed.

Comment: the line `$asset->alt` is wrong and should be: `{{$asset->alt}}`. It looks like asset is not an object. So I think its null. What is the value of $asset?

Comment: Ah thats just a typo in the question. The point is else should not even be run but it is and so is if

Answer (score 1):

The if-empty block only checks if `$data` is empty, it does not ensure that the items *in* the array are actual objects.

Take this PHP code as an example:

```
$data = [1, 2, 3];

if (empty($data))
{
   echo "It's empty!";
}
else
{
   foreach ($data as $asset)
   {
      echo $asset->alt;
   }
}
```

The above code will throw the same error, since `1`, `2` and `3` are not objects.

Comment: Data is an object in my controller how come it is not in my view?

Comment: @panthro `$data` *is* an object/array in your view. It is the individual items in your `$data` array that aren't objects.

Comment: @panthro - where do you get that array from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@if(count($data))
   @foreach($data as $asset)
      {{$asset->alt}}
   @endforeach
@else
   It's empty!
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compare `$data` against null

```
if ($data == null)
{
   echo "It's empty!";
}
else
{
   foreach ($data as $asset)
   {
      echo $asset->alt;
   }
}
```